# How decode string on PowerShell

Tags: powershell, utf

I have file with string like this

> \u0440\u043e

How I can decode this string on PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [regex unescape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```
[regex]::Unescape("\u0440\u043e")
```

*Output:*

```
ро
```